# SELECT DECODE statement: changing both null values and non-null values

Tags: select, null, decode

I've spent hours trying to figure this out but keep getting errors!

Basically I want to keep all field values except change the null values and '0' values. I want to change '0' to No Charge, and all null values to 'Not Applicable'.

The closest I've come up with is

```
SELECT DECODE(NVL(TO_CHAR(PL.oper),'No'),'0','No Charge','No','Not Applicable',PL.oper)
```

No error comes up when I use this code. 0's all change to 'No Charge', but the Null values stay the same for some reason.
Because my request is so specific, I can't find anything like this on this website or on Google. If anyone could help me, I'd really appreciate it!!!

Thank you

Comment: Try without NVL function,bcoz the decode function treats two nulls as equal.

Comment: What do you mean? (Sorry I'm a SQL beginner). I want to mark null values as "Not Applicable" and therefore I don't know how to change null values with NVL function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with case-statement anyway in this case.

```
SELECT id, 
       field,
       CASE NVL(field, 'No')
       WHEN '0' THEN 'No Charge'
       WHEN 'No' THEN 'Not applicable'
       ELSE 'catch all result do this'
       END
FROM   xx_test
```

[link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2414723?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: how would I format ELSE to keep everything else as is? "ELSE PL.oper"? id.field?